# How to Copy Contents of Two or Three Canvas to Another Canvas Locally

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

i have some layers of canvas:

```
<canvas id="layer1" width="700" height="700" class="pageCanvas">   </canvas>
<canvas id="layer2"  width="700" height="700" class="pageCanvas">   </canvas>
<canvas id="layer3"  width="700" height="700" class="pageCanvas">   </canvas>
```

and i'd like to put images of canvases

> layer1 and layer2

to canvas

> layer3.

I'll be glad if you write down the code because I couldn't find any good explanation over the internet.

thanks``

Answer (score 1):

combine two canvas and put it to layer3:

```
var canvas1 = document.getElementById('layer1');

var canvas2 = document.getElementById('layer2');

var canvas3 = document.getElementById('layer3');

canvas3.drawImage(canvas1, 0, 0);

canvas3.drawImage(canvas2, 0, 0);
```